# Bot framework: “Sorry, my bot code is having an issue”. Fixed bug but how to restart conversation?

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger

I have a simple Bot created using Microsoft Bot Framework running on Azure and it was working fine on all channels. Until yesterday when it stopped working on Facebook messenger when a user chose a particular untested option.

These are the lines that get executed when the rogue option is selected:

```
string replyText = "I am not yet ready to answer this question. Please choose another option.";

            switch (appointmentBookType){
                case Option1:
                    //Call Option1 Dialog.
                    break;
                case Option2:
                    //Call Option2 Dialog.
                    break;
```

I keep getting "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" as a response to anything I type.

This is the error I see in the Bot Framework developer portal for facebook messenger:
"There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError"

I am only using dialogs with some HeroCards.
I do not use LUIS.

I have fixed the bug by handling this previously unhandled conditions.
Is there a way to restart the conversation after fixing the bug?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some scouring, this finally worked: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/technical-faq/#my-bot-is-stuck--how-can-i-reset-the-conversation

Comment: Url Dead (like all the Microsoft Bot Documentation is dead all urls just point to the pointless homepage now)